# What is causing memory access error here?

Tags: c

I do not understand what is causing the memory access error here.

I made this simple example which shows my problem:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct mycanvas {
    void *pixels;
} mycanvas;

main()
{
    void* testchunk;  
    testchunk = (void*) calloc (1024 * 768 * 4,sizeof(char));

    struct mycanvas* new_canvas;
    new_canvas->pixels=testchunk; //causes memory access error
}
```

What needs to be changed to get it to run? This is gcc on Linux.

Comment: What is `new_canvas` pointing at?

Comment: This won't compile as C++. Are you sure you're not coding in C instead?

Comment: I highly recommend you to use `main` as a function which returns an integer, like: `int main(void)`...

Comment: @PeterVaro In C, leaving off the return type actually gives you a function that returns an int. Poor general practice, but that's the way the spec rolls, so making the change you suggest wouldn't change anything about the code.

Comment: @mah yepp 1) my suggestion has nothing to do with question, yes, but 2) afaik it is the standard to do it that way. Only very old C codes didn't use integer as a return value of main, expected it would be anyway.

Comment: @PeterVaro: If nothing is specified as a function's return-type `int` is assumed.

Comment: Not anymore, implicit int is not in the current language spec, C99. @alk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct mycanvas {
    void *pixels;
} mycanvas;

int main()
{
    void* testchunk;  
    testchunk = (void*) calloc (1024 * 768 * 4,sizeof(char));

    mycanvas *new_canvas = malloc(sizeof(struct mycanvas));
    new_canvas->pixels=testchunk; //now everything is ok

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have never initialized `new_canvas`. Most likely, you want to do this:

```
struct mycanvas new_canvas;
new_canvas.pixels=testchunk;
```

Comment: I thought I could initialize it with this statement:

    "struct mycanvas* new_canvas;"

This makes new_canvas a pointer and therefore the next statement
is:
 "new_canvas->pixels=testchunk;"

Comment: @Georg making a pointer isn't enough. You have to make it point somewhere valid before you use what it points at.

Answer (score -1):

I guess I figured it out now:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct mycanvas {
    void *pixels;
} mycanvas;

main(){
    void* testchunk;  
    testchunk = (void*) calloc (1024 * 768 * 4,sizeof(char));

    struct mycanvas* new_canvas=(mycanvas*)malloc(sizeof(mycanvas));

    new_canvas->pixels=testchunk; 
}
```

Thank you for your help! By the way, since I use cpp I could use "new" instead of malloc.

Comment: This is worse than the version with `struct mycanvas new_canvas; struct mycanvas *new_canvas2 = &new_canvas;`. In this version you have to `free` afterwards but in that version you didn't.

Comment: This code is illegal in C++ because you did not declare a return type for `main`. Also you said in the initial post that you use gcc (not g++).

Comment: You are clearly *not* using C+. If you were, you'd include `<cstdlib>`, you wouldn't typedef your structs, you wouldn't have to use struct in the declaration of variables, you wouldn't have to cast the result of `malloc` and `calloc`, you'd need a return type for `main`, and probably more stuff I'm missing. You are clearly writing C code. If you're *hoping* to write C++, you're doing it all wrong. Definitely pick up [a good book on the language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).